# Visual Studio UI Improvement OCD Mode

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface

I am wondering if anyone knows how to pull this off.  Here goes.

I have a multi monitor setup, and I maximize Visual Studio to both windows.  I create a new vertical document tab control, so that I have one document tab control in each physical screen.  This is fine.

Now, I want to be able to make them work as if they were connected.  I want to have the designer on one side, and the code related to the displayed designer on the other window.

I'd like it to have the following functionality:

1. If a item is double clicked on the solution explorer, open designer/code in both tabs.
2. When a document is selected in either pane, open appropriate file in the other pane.
3. Make the designer view refresh on edit, or periodically.

Any ideas on how I could pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check (wait) for VS 2010 (beta now). There should be multi monitor support.